# Is it Possible to Use EF Core in an MVC site Using Just One Table?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, database-design, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Say I have a table in the database with data already populated (imported from excel).

I am building an MVC website using .NET Core and EF Core (both v.1.1.2)

What I'm wanting to do create a series of models, whose data is derived from one original "source data" table. The source data table has 150 columns, and although I don't need them all right now, I do want to retain all columns so that I might be able to use them at a later time if needed.

Using the "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold" command, I was able to generate a:

- **Model** - with all public get/set properties for each column
- **DbContext** Class - with DbSet & Fluent API statements to reference the table and columns

With this setup, is it possible to setup a sort of "virtual" relational data model with EF Core by simply creating various Model classes (many-to-many relationships) and their properties equal to the properties already defined in the original "source" entity?

What I'm hoping to avoid is having to maintain an actual relational data structure in the DB (independent tables linked by PKs, FKs, join tables, etc.)

Reason being...  I'll only be looking to do a nightly update of the source data table from bulk import of Excel worksheet and will not have to persist or track any changes to the data (read only). So, I'd like to not have to deal with the additional overhead/setup/maintenance involved with mapping the source data to relational tables, columns, keys, etc. during the import.

Can I simply create various models, then in the DbContext, override the OnModelCreating method passing an instance of modelBuilder to map those DbSet entities to the columns in the source table?

```
namespace VTracker.Contexts
{

    public partial class DataContext : DbContext
    {

        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<SourceData> Data { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SomeModel1> Model1 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SomeModel2> Model2 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SomeModel3> Model3 { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<SourceData>(entity =>
            {
                // some key must be defined?
                entity.HasKey(e => e.SourceIDColumn);

                entity.ToTable("SourceDataTable");

                entity.Property(e => e.SourceIDColumn)

                entity.Property(e => e.SourceColumn1)
                    .HasColumnName("SourceColumn1")

                // ...... continue mapping .....

                // Some Model 1 Entity Builder

                entity.ToTable("SourceDataTable");

                // ...... continue mapping .....

                // Some Model 2 Entity Builder

                entity.ToTable("SourceDataTable");

                // .... and so on for other models......

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Or would it be better to just use the one entity for everything and just build out SQL / LINQ queries to retrieve/join the data as needed?

Comment: Have you considered creating views in your database and then map the views to your models?

Comment: @Brad hmm there's an idea! I have not thought about that... I forgot all about views! It's an idea, and one that can be implemented without too much effort. I'll give it a try and see how it goes. I still wonder though... Is there a way do it directly with EF? Either way, thanks for the suggestion!!